# Как сделать меню свернутым при загрузке?

Tags: html, jquery, css, адаптивная-верстка, меню

Я сделал адаптивное меню, но при загрузке страницы оно уже развернуто, а нужно, чтобы было свернутым. Я пытался пофиксить это, добавляя к  `#menu-item` свойство `display: block;` после нажатия на кнопку, но тогда элементы меню выстраиваются горизонтально. Хочу, чтобы меню было закрытым при загрузке и элементы выстроены вертикально...

```js
$(function() {
 $('#ham').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').toggle(650);
  $('nav a').addClass('dropdown-on');
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
 }

 #ham {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin:-40px 15px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 
 #menu-item {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }

 #menu-item:last-child{
  margin-bottom:  10px;
 }
 #ham:hover, #menu-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.55;
  color: wheat;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Orion</a></h1>
<nav>
  <i class="fa fa-bars" id="ham">V</i>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item" href="#sel">Shop</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item" href="#sss">About</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item" href="#">Blog</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item" href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: тегу `nav` добавить стиль `display:none;` (а при клике в js менять на `inline-block`) - элемент скроется и место занимать не будет, если вы хотите убирать видимость, а место оставлять, воспользуйтесь `visibility:hidden;`.

Comment: если добавить тегу нав стиль display: none; тогда не будет видно кнопки

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так: на jQuery обрабатываем а само меню свёрнуто

```js
$(function() {
  $('.unit').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
}

.unit {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.unit:hover i {
  background: #000;
}

.unit i {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.unit,
.menu {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.menu {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-10000px, 0);
}

.visible {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top">
  <span class="unit"> 
     <i></i> 
     <i></i>
     <i></i> 
   </span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cinema</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tauch my</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">potrfolio</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ужастно сделано, id это уникальный идетификатор, его нельзя задавать более чем одному элементу, не задавай id чему попало.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.open-menu').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown').toggle(650);
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.open-menu { /** при обычно разрешении скрываешь **/
    display: none;
}
.dropdown__item {;
    text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width 768px) { /* ну  тут свое поставишь разрешение */
    .open-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown__item {
        display: block
     }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
      <a class="logo" href="index.html">Orion</a> <!--тоже странная штука, если это лого то просто <a href="index.html">Orion</a> без h1, h1 это заголовок страницы. -->
      <i class="fa fa-bars open-menu">≡</i>
      <nav class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown__item" href="#sel">Shop</a>
          <a class="dropdown__item" href="#sss">About</a>
          <a class="dropdown__item" href="#">Blog</a>
          <a class="dropdown__item" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте по порядку:
1. id должны различаться!
2. скопировал форматирование в .dropdown
3. в hover отображаем меню

```css
 
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

nav:hover >.dropdown{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Orion</a></h1>
<nav>
  <i class="fa fa-bars" id="ham">V</i>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item1" href="#sel">Shop</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item2" href="#sss">About</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item3" href="#">Blog</a>
  <a class="dropdown" id="menu-item4" href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```