# сделать свернутое меню при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Я сделал меню , в нем 42 раздела. при загрузке сайта, оно сразу развернуто.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы оно было свернуто при загрузке и разворачивалось по клику на блок "категории"?

```html
<div class="category-menu">
  <div class="category-heading">
    <h2 class="categories-toggle"><span>Категории</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="cate-toggle" class="category-menu-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="shop-left-sidebar.html">IT: Бизнес</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-left-sidebar.html">Аналитика</a></li>
      .......
      <li><a href="shop-left-sidebar.html">Экономика</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А где css какие классы отвечают за состояние или скрипты? А что вы уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать меню свернутым при загрузке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761262/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой рабочий пример, но без нажатий на меню. Раскрытие по наведению мыши

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Interface</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/topNav.css">


</head>
<body>

<div class="topNavRespMenu" onclick="topNavRespMenu()">MENU</div>
<div class="topNavCentring" id="topNavCentring">
  <div class="topNavContainer">
      <div class="topNavMenu">MENU1
          <div class="topNavContentContainer">
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 1</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 2</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 3</div>
          </div>
      </div
      ><div class="topNavMenu">MENU2
          <div class="topNavContentContainer">
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 1</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 2</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 3</div>
          </div>
      </div
      ><div class="topNavMenu">MENU3
          <div class="topNavContentContainer">
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 1</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 2</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 3</div>
          </div>
      </div
      ><div class="topNavMenu">MENU4
          <div class="topNavContentContainer">
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 1</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 2</div>
            <div class="topNavDropdownContent">OPTION 3</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И CSS

```
.topNavCentring{
    top: -40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 99%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: "topNavShow";
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-name: "topNavShow";
    animation-duration: 800ms;
}
.topNavRespMenu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.topNavRespMenu::after{
    content: ' \2261 ';
    font-size: 66px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px
}

/*  MAIN MENU SELECTION */
.topNavContainer{
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.topNavMenu{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    background: #08E8DE;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: context-menu;
    transition: 300ms;
    transition: background 300ms ease-out;
}
.topNavMenu:hover .topNavContentContainer {
    display: block;
}
.topNavMenu:hover{
    background: #00FFFF;
}
.topNavContentContainer {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius:8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-name: "topNavDropdownShadow";
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-name: "topNavDropdown";
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
.topNavDropdownContent{
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: context-menu;
    transition: background 200ms ease-out;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-name: "topNavDropdown";
    -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-name: "topNavDropdown";
    animation-duration: 300ms;
}
.topNavDropdownContent:hover{
    background-color: #00DDDD;
    color: #000000;
}

/* DELAY STARTING ANIMATION FOR DROPDOWN CONTENT */
.topNavContentContainer > div:nth-child(1){animation-delay: 0ms }
.topNavContentContainer > div:nth-child(2){animation-delay: 100ms }
.topNavContentContainer > div:nth-child(3){animation-delay: 200ms }
.topNavContentContainer > div:nth-child(4){animation-delay: 300ms }
.topNavContentContainer > div:nth-child(5){animation-delay: 400ms }


/* DROPDOWN MENU ANIMATION */
@keyframes topNavShow{
    from {top: -40px;} to {top: 10px;}
}
@keyframes topNavDropdownShadow {
    from {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
}
@keyframes topNavDropdown {
    from {opacity: 0;transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg);}
    50% {opacity: 0.5;transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg);}
    to {opacity: 1;transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg);}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .topNavCentring{
        padding-top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .topNavRespMenu{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .topNavContainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 60px);
        padding: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .topNavMenu{
        display: block;
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 60px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 28px;
        cursor: context-menu;
        transition: 0ms;
    }

    .topNavContentContainer {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    
    .topNavDropdownContent{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 60px;
        color: #000000;
        font-family: "Titillium Web";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        -webkit-animation-name: none;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0ms;
        animation-name: none;
        animation-duration: 0ms;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Элементы меню, которые должны быть скрыты, в CSS display:none
И Javascript document.getElementById("ElmName").style.display="block";